# Как работать с postgresql в docker?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker-compose

Так уж вышло, что пришлось работать с `django` проектом в `docker`, первый раз. Сейчас у меня при попытке применить миграции командой

```
docker-compose run --rm rest python manage.py migrate
```

Выскакивает ошибка `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column account_instagramgeograficsanalitics.city does not exist`

Я думал почикать таблицу, но не пойму как залезть в базу. Как в докере добраться к моей  `postgresql` БД? Сохранность  не волнует, можно даже полностью снести.

Comment: Обычно база кладется снаружи контейнера

Comment: Команда `sudo -u postgres psql` из консоли выдает `sudo: неизвестный пользователь: postgres
sudo: не удаётся инициализировать модуль политики`

Comment: Зачем судо?) есть су.

Comment: `docker exec -it  имя контейнера /bin/bash или sh` там уже через `psql -U как обычно` посмотреть имя контейнера можно через `docker ps`

Answer (score 0):

Хранилище самой базы обычно находиться снаружи контейнера, чтобы при его перезапуске ваша база не обнулялась, происходит это обычно монтированием директории где будут лежать данные.

Но чтобы получить доступ к базе как к таковой вам нужно соотвествующие `GUI` Вы можете установить его напрямую в контейнер или найти готовый образ. Можно так-же напрямую обращаться к базе через `bash`, для этого смотрите в сторону команды `docker exec`, с помощью этой команды вы получите доступ к башу контейнера вашей базы.

Comment: В инструкции по сборке контейнера есть вызов консоли Postgres: `docker-compose run --rm db psql -h db -U postgres`. Но у меня эта команда вызывает  `ERROR: No such service: db`

Comment: @lepiloff так, это немного отступает от изначальной темы. Как вы запускаете проект и базу данных?

Comment: Запускаю стандартно docker-compose up

Comment: Что находиться в `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Что там искать? Просто он 260 строк

Comment: @lepiloff Запуск контейнера с базой данных.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант можно использовать:
`docker-compose run --rm rest python manage.py dbshell` - это тоже самое, что и `psql`